# matrix multiply every pair of 2-D arrays along first dimension with einsum

Tags: python, numpy

I have two 3-D arrays of the same size `a` and `b`

```
np.random.seed([3,14159])
a = np.random.randint(10, size=(4, 3, 2))
b = np.random.randint(10, size=(4, 3, 2))
```

---

```
print(a)

[[[4 8]
  [1 1]
  [9 2]]

 [[8 1]
  [4 2]
  [8 2]]

 [[8 4]
  [9 4]
  [3 4]]

 [[1 5]
  [1 2]
  [6 2]]]
```

---

```
print(b)

[[[7 7]
  [1 1]
  [7 8]]

 [[7 4]
  [8 0]
  [0 9]]

 [[3 8]
  [7 7]
  [2 6]]

 [[3 1]
  [9 3]
  [0 5]]]
```

I want to take the first array from a

```
a[0]

[[4 8]
 [1 1]
 [9 2]]
```

And the first one from `b`

```
b[0]

[[7 7]
 [1 1]
 [7 8]]
```

And return this

```
a[0].T.dot(b[0])

[[ 92 101]
 [ 71  73]]
```

But I want to do this over the entire first dimension.  I thought I could use `np.einsum`

```
np.einsum('abc,ade->ace', a, b)

[[[210 224]
  [165 176]]

 [[300 260]
  [ 75  65]]

 [[240 420]
  [144 252]]

 [[ 96  72]
  [108  81]]]
```

This is the correct shape, but not values.

I expect to get this:

```
np.array([x.T.dot(y).tolist() for x, y in zip(a, b)])

[[[ 92 101]
  [ 71  73]]

 [[ 88 104]
  [ 23  22]]

 [[ 93 145]
  [ 48  84]]

 [[ 12  34]
  [ 33  21]]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix multiplication amounts to a sum of products where the sum is taken over the middle axis, so the index `b` should be the same for both arrays: (i.e. change `ade` to `abe`):

```
In [40]: np.einsum('abc,abe->ace', a, b)
Out[40]: 
array([[[ 92, 101],
        [ 71,  73]],

       [[ 88, 104],
        [ 23,  22]],

       [[ 93, 145],
        [ 48,  84]],

       [[ 12,  34],
        [ 33,  21]]])
```

---

When the input arrays have index subscripts that are missing in the output array, 
they are summed over independently. That is,

```
np.einsum('abc,ade->ace', a, b)
```

is equivalent to

```
In [44]: np.einsum('abc,ade->acebd', a, b).sum(axis=-1).sum(axis=-1)
Out[44]: 
array([[[210, 224],
        [165, 176]],

       [[300, 260],
        [ 75,  65]],

       [[240, 420],
        [144, 252]],

       [[ 96,  72],
        [108,  81]]])
```

Comment: Thank you.  That helps clarify what I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one with [`np.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) as we need to push back the second axis of `a` to the end, so that it would get `sum-reduced` against the second axis from `b`, while keeping their first axes aligned -

```
np.matmul(a.swapaxes(1,2),b)
```

Schematically put :

At start :

```
a   :  M x N X R1
b   :  M x N X R2
```

With swapped axes for a :

```
a   :  M x R1 X [N]
b   :  M x [N] X R2
```

The bracketed axes get `sum-reduced`, leaving us with :

```
out :   M x R1 X R2
```

---

On Python 3.x, `matmul` is taken care of with [`@ operator`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) -

```
a.swapaxes(1,2) @ b
```

Comment: I was not aware of `np.matmul`.  Thank you.